# Remove duplicates using only where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Today, i got a problem from a friend.

Problem - Write a SQL query using UNION ALL(not union) that uses the where clause to eliminate duplicates.

- I can not use group by expression
- I can not use unique , distinct keywords.

Input -

```
 id(Table 1)  
 1
 2

 fk_id(Table 2)
 1
 1
 2
```

I gave him the solution below query

```
select id from
(
select id , row_number() over(partition by id order by id) rn from
(
select id from T1
union all
select fk_ID id from T2
)
)where rn = 1;

Output - 
id
1
2
```

which is generating unique id's.

Now suspense by him i also can not use row_number(). i just have to use where condition. i am writing query on oracle database.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting academic question with possibly no practical application at all.

Comment: Why can we not use row_number() ?

Comment: @BobC according to the question i only have to use where clause to get the desired results. Please suggest.

Comment: My question is *why*? Is this some sort of science experiment, or is there are real business case here?

Comment: No, this is not a real business case. He just got the question in SQL exam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From its name and the data shown, we can assume that `id` in table `t1` is unique.

From its name and the data shown, we can assume that `fk_id` in table `t2` is a foreign key to `table1.id`.

So the union of the IDs in the two tables are simply the IDs that we find in table `t1`.

As we are forced to use `UNION ALL` on the two tables, though, we can use a pseudo UNION ALL not adding anything:

```
select id from t1
union all
select fk_id from t2 where 1 = 2;
```

If `t2.fk_id` were not a foreign key referencing `t1.id`, we would use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` in the where clause instead. If this is to give a result without duplicates, however, there must be no duplicates in `t2` then to start with. (As you are showing that duplicate values in `t2` do exist, this approach would not work then.) Here is a query for unique values from `t1` plus unique values from `t2` that are not referencing the `t1` values:

```
select id from t1
union all
select fk_id from t2 where fk_id not in (select id from t1);
```

Comment: Can you please write the query when there is no primary foreign key relationship between the table?

Comment: this query will work in you case too. if their is no primary and foreign key

Comment: Sorry, I thought the query was so simple that the hint on using `NOT IN` / `NOT EXISTS` would suffice. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry again. I was confused. When there are duplicate values in `t2` (as your sample data is showing) and they are not referencing the `t1` values (so you could have a duplicate value that is not in `t1`), then you cannot get rid of them without `UNION` / `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY` or any such approach. You'd have to make them distinct somehow, which the `WHERE` clause alone cannot provide.

Comment: If this is Oracle only and Oracle's propriatary `ROWNUM` or `ROWID` are allowed, then see Aleksej's answer. (Using `ROWID` instead of generating a unique ID with `ROWNUM` would be the much simpler approach, however.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, for understanding the question and your efforts. .Yes, when using oracle using rowid is simple approach as compared to generating unique id

Answer (score 2):

In a more generic case, where you can have duplicates in both tables, this could be a way.

**test data:**

```
create table table1(id) as (  
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual
)

create table table2(fk_id) as (
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual 
)
```

**query:**

```
with tab1_union_all_tab2 as ( 
    select 'tab1'||rownum as uniqueId, id    from table1 UNION ALL
    select 'tab2'||rownum            , fk_id from table2
)    
select id
from tab1_union_all_tab2 u1
where not exists ( select 1
                   from tab1_union_all_tab2 u2
                   where u1.id = u2.id
                     and u1.uniqueId < u2.uniqueId
                 )
```

**result:**

```
    ID
----------
         3
         4
         1
         2
```

This should clarify the idea behind:

```
with tab1_union_all_tab2 as ( 
    select 'tab1'||rownum as uniqueId, id    from table1 UNION ALL
    select 'tab2'||rownum            , fk_id from table2
)    
select uniqueId, id,
       ( select nvl(listagg ( uniqueId, ', ') within group ( order by uniqueId), 'NO DUPLICATES')
          from tab1_union_all_tab2 u2
         where u1.id = u2.id
           and u1.uniqueId < u2.uniqueId
       ) duplicates
from tab1_union_all_tab2 u1

UNIQUEID           ID DUPLICATES
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
tab11               1 tab12, tab15, tab21, tab22, tab23, tab26
tab12               1 tab15, tab21, tab22, tab23, tab26
tab13               2 tab14, tab28
tab14               2 tab28
tab15               1 tab21, tab22, tab23, tab26
tab21               1 tab22, tab23, tab26
tab22               1 tab23, tab26
tab23               1 tab26
tab24               3 NO DUPLICATES
tab25               4 tab27
tab26               1 NO DUPLICATES
tab27               4 NO DUPLICATES
tab28               2 NO DUPLICATES
```

As rightly observed by Thorsten Kettner, you can easily edit this to use `rowid` instead of building a unique id by concatenating a string and the `rownum`:

```
with tab1_union_all_tab2 as ( 
    select rowid uniqueId, id    from table1 UNION ALL
    select rowid           , fk_id from table2
)    
select id
from tab1_union_all_tab2 u1
where not exists ( select 1
                   from tab1_union_all_tab2 u2
                   where u1.id = u2.id
                     and u1.uniqueId < u2.uniqueId
                 )
```

Comment: For Oracle this is a great solution, working even with possible duplicate values in both tables. (The same can be done by simply using Oracle's `ROWID` by the way, so you don't have to generate a unique row ID yourself.) The answer would have been even better with a brief explanation what the query is doing and why you decided for this approach. +1 from me.

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

write a where statement for the second select in the union all as where id != fk_id